# Window shutter effect for a website

Tags: css, window, effect, shutter

I would like your help.  I want to design a website for a friend who works with windows shutters, blinds, rolls..etc so, I  want to include the effect that a **shutter** is in front of the pictures and when you click on them is rolling upwards like a window shutter. I tried the roll upwards effect with ccs3 but it does not look natural. Can you give me your lights please?

Comment: Please post code, what you've tried already and an example of what you want to achieve. We're here to help, but not to do your work. http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: <html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script> 
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#flip").click(function(){
        $("#panel").slideToggle(4000);
    });
});
</script>
 
<style> 
#panel, #flip, {
    
    text-align: center;
}

#panel {
    padding: 50px;
}
body {
    background:url(win2.jpg);

 background-repeat:no-repeat;
 background-position:center;
 
}

</style>

<head>
<body>
<div id="flip"> 
<div id="panel">
<img src="blinds.jpg" alt="window" height="768" width="1024">
</div>
</div>

</body>

Comment: I have edited the blind.jpg to have some black stripes on which is the same picture as my background picture, and I have added the slide up function.